# Facebook Graph API console error

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to display the feed into my console using a console.log however it is returning an error of no token.

message: "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."
type: "OAuthException" error code : 2500;

the message above is what I am getting. I have followed the steps given by FB.

The code is bellow.

```
<script>

 window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.1',

    });
    FB.api('/me', {fields: 'last_name'}, function(response) {
    console.log(response);
     });

  };



  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_UK/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));   


</script>
<div id="fb-root">
</div>
```

Comment: The user needs to login before you can call /me

Comment: I have logged into facebook and got the access token,

Comment: i don´t see any login code. how exactly did you login the user? and calling an api function right after init without checking if the user is logged in is a bad idea...

Comment: What does the code for login look like? And what access token?

Comment: FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    console.log('Logged in.');
  }
  else {
    FB.login();
  }
});

Comment: I have added this  after the FB.init function

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call the API without asking the user to login first. Instead, remove the `FB.api` line in your code and replace it with the below:

```
FB.login(function(){
  FB.api('/me', 'get', {fields: 'last_name'}, function (response ) {
    console.log(response);
  });
});
```

Ideally, you should call the above login code when a "Login" button is pressed, e.g.:

```
<button type="button" onclick="doLogin();">Login to Facebook</button>
```

(Remember to wrap the `FB.login()` function in the `doLogin()` function.)

Comment: Hi add the code however it is stating that I don't have a active access token,
error: Object
code: 2500
message: "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."
type: "OAuthException"
I do have  vaild token.

Comment: You need to log the user in to get an access_token. The above code is what you can use to log the user in.

Comment: Call it using `onclick` of a button. E.g. `<button type="button" onclick="doLogin();">Login to Facebook</button>`